# Are Ruby symbols the equivalent of PHP constants?

Tags: php, ruby, symbols

It seems like there might be a difference on the memory-front, but otherwise, they seem fairly similar. Any differences I should be aware of?

Comment: Can't PHP constant refer to anything?

Comment: @sawa - no they cant, for example you cannot put an object in a constant. Until recently you could only put primitives in there ( if I recall PHP7 allows arrays for constants now ).  That said I don't know how Ruby does it.  But saying `anything` is way to broad ... :-p

Comment: I see. But it seems that PHP still allows much more things to be referred to as a constant.

Comment: There are user defined global constants `define('Constant', $value )` and class constants  `class foo{ const Constant = 1; }` and  access with `foo:Constant;`  You can also go `$var = 'foo';` and then `$var::Constant;` but that might blow your mind.

Comment: In either case `class constants` or `defined constants` you cant change the value at run time.  That is why they are constants.  Class constants are useful because they don't mess up the global space, and can be easier to locate then the global ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Symbols in ruby and constants in PHP are not really equivalent.

Most ruby implementations keep something called a symbol table that is internal to the interpreter. The symbol table stores identifiers used throughout a program, like method names, class names, and so on in said table. Lookups of said names are performed based on the integer position of said names in the symbol table.

Symbols themselves are objects, and there is a 1-to-1 correspondence between symbol names and Symbol objects. So when you have e.g. `def hello ...` and call the `hello` method somewhere in a program, this is referring to the exact same object as if you'd referred to `:hello`. The symbol table is basically a way to avoid doing a bunch of string comparisons when referring to commonly-used names throughout a program.

To illustrate, consider the following code:

```
class A
  def hello
    puts "the method name is #{__method__}"
    puts "the class of the method name is #{__method__.class}"
    puts "the object ID of the name hello is #{__method__.__id__}"
  end
end

A.new.hello
puts "the object id of :hello is #{:hello.__id__}"
```

This outputs:

```
$ the method name is hello
the class of the method name is Symbol
the object ID of the name hello is 898268
the object id of :hello is 898268
```

So, the method name 'hello' and the symbol :hello refer to the same object. Storing symbols in this way reduces object allocations -- as you hinted at -- and by extension makes looking up commonly-used names in a program much faster.

Also, you can't assign values to symbols. e.g., `:hello = "blah"` won't work. Because :hello has a very concrete value according to the internal symbol table. So that's another obvious difference between ruby symbols and PHP constants.

In PHP, a constant is an identifier bound to a value where the value is immutable for the duration of the program's execution. The value can be any object or value. If you have two PHP constants that refer to the same value, e.g. `define("A", "value")` and `define("B", "value")`, then this is actually two separate identifiers pointing to two unique values.

So while `A` and `B` there point to the same semantic content, they do not point to a single identifiable object. And they do not reduce to a single identifiable object by referencing them. There's no internal store in PHP that keeps a map of common symbols-to-ids like there is for symbols in ruby. So I would not say that ruby symbols are the equivalent of PHP constants at all.

[1] - https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html

Comment: "Most ruby implementations keep something called a symbol table that is internal to the interpreter. " – Pretty much all language implementations have something like that, including (I'm guessing) most PHP implementations (P8, Quercus, Peachpie, etc.). The difference is that Ruby, Smalltalk, Lisp, Erlang, Elixir, etc. expose it to the programmer.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Since humans are the ones programming things... understand?

Answer (score 0):

They have nothing to do with each other. Asking about their differences is like asking about the differences between a Toyota Corolla and the color blue.

A *constant* is (as a first approximation) a variable that can only be assigned once, during initialization. A constant is an immutable *reference to a value*.

A symbol is a value that represents the idea of a "name" (in the programming language sense), an "identifier" (again, in the programming language sense), or a "label". Just like a string is a value that represents the idea of "text". Symbols are immutable, immediate, and they evaluate to themselves.

So, symbols are values, constants are not. (Constants are references *to* values). Symbols evaluate to themselves, constants evaluate to whatever value they reference. The symbol datatype essentially exposes something to the programmer that most language implementations (including Peachpie, P8, Quercus, and the other PHP implementations) have but that is usually not exposed: a symbol table. Symbols aren't unique to Ruby, they also exist in Smalltalk (where Ruby got them from), Newspeak, Self, most Lisps (including Clojure, Scheme, CommonLisp), Elixir, Erlang, ECMAScript, Scala, and many others.